# Add css to component via service in Angular2, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have an component `A` with 5 pictures. Only 1 picture has colour and is clickable, the other 4 are grey with help of this css class

```
.not_opened{
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(85%);
}
```

And are not clickable.

If I click on the first picture, I change component to `component` `B` (`A` disappears, because it is separate component, not child or parent) , do some manipulations in the new second `component B` and then I click the button, which returns me to `component A`. Everything stays the same there, but I would like to make 2 picture not grey ( so delete/change this class not_opened from picture 2) and make it clickable, then if I click picture 2 I go to third `component C` and then back and third picture is now not grey and clickable and so on...

How could I make something like this?
First thought was to make 4 different components, each with own css stylesheet, but maybe there is another way?..
Maybe somehow with help of service?
Could you please advice me something?

Comment: use ng-class to apply conditional class : http://angular-craft.com/css-in-angular-2-ng-class-and-view-encapsulation/

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest you to introduce a view-model notion to your project. View-model contains information on how to render a particular model. In your case you can pass something like `Array<ImageViewModel>` between components `A` and `B`. You can pass this data through some service if you find it suitable for your case, or you can use parent component, e.g.:

Parent component template:

```
<component-a [images]="images" *ngIf="active === 'a'" (onImageSelected)="handleImageSelected($event)"></component-a>
<component-b [images]="images" *ngIf="active === 'b'" (onSettingsEditCompleted)="handleSettingsEditCompleted()"></component-b>
```

Parent component code:

```
.... {
    images: Array<ImageViewModel> = [];
    active: string = "a";

    constructor(private _service: ImageService) {
        // Lets imagine that service returns array of image urls.
        this._service.fetchImages().subscribe((urls) => {
            this.images = urls.map(url => ({src: url, disabled: true}));
            if (this.images.length > 0) {
                this.images[0].disabled = false;  
            }
        });
    }

    handleImageSelected(image: ImageViewModel) {
        this.active = "b";
        console.log("Image selected", image); 
    }

    handleSettingsEditCompleted() {
        this.active = "a";
    }
}
```

And where `ImageViewModel` is something like:

```
interface ImageViewModel {
    src: string;
    disabled: boolean;
}
```

Now in `componentA` use `[ngClass]` directive in order to change image availability.

ComponentA template:

```
<img *ngFor="let image of images" [src]="image.src" [ngClass]="{'not-opened': image.disabled}" (click)='!image.disabled && handleImageSelected(image)'/>
```

ComponentA styles:

```
.not-opened {
    filter: grayscale(85%); // Why do you use -webkit version only? 
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(85%);
}
```

ComponentA code:

```
... {
   @Output()
   onImageSelected = new EventEmitter<ImageViewModel>();
   @Input() 
   images: Array<ImageViewModel> = [];   

   handleImageSelected(image: ImageViewModel) {
       this.images[1].disabled = false;
       this.onImageSelected.emit(image);
   }
}
```

Read about `@Input` and `@Output` annotations at Angular documentation if something is not clear.